# Exception when sending message to disconnected client in SignalR

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

In a Hub, I am sending a message to a client using

```
try { 
    GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ContextManagerHub>().Clients.Client(connectionID).SendMessage(message);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    HandleError(ex);
}
```

The connectionId is stored using OnConnected and removed using OnDisconnected on the Hub.
I am a little worried that I am sending messages to disconnected clients, and would like to get exceptions if I do. But the code above never raises exception, even if I try using connectionID = "BAD_ID". Anyone got an idea on how to figure out if the SendMessage actually fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So SignalR does not actually validate if your sending to an invalid ConnectionId.  The reason why this does not occur is because ConnectionId's for clients are a lot like SignalR groups.  They reference a topic that can be subscribed and published to.

Therefore when sending to an invalid ConnectionId you push a message to a topic that doesn't exist yet; so it's created.  The reasoning behind this is if a client happens to come to the server with that connection id via a reconnect or by other means they will then receive any messages that they had missed during their down time.

Sooo for your case I'd recommend tracking clients via the OnConnected and OnDisconnected methods and then running logic to verify that they are present prior to sending to them.